# ie vertical space issues in lists

Tags: css, list

I've fixed the vertical spacing issues, thanks to all the posts but my problem is with border now, if I apply the border, the list item gains a height of 2 px.

Update: added overflow:hidden, now the height of the list item is 1px
Update: added screenshot of chrome (desired output)

```
ul.lines {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
.lines li {
border-bottom: solid red 1px;
list-style: none;
background-color:#00F;
}
.lt-ie9 .lines li {
background-color: #CC0;
font-size: 0px;
line-height: 0px;
height: 0px !important;
overflow: hidden
}


<ul class="lines">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Edit: My list items are intentionally empty, they'll have just borders, and context of my use is vertical lines across bar charts.

[image: IE]

[image: My desired output (screenshot from Chrome)]

Comment: nothing, empty list, I'm using them to draw lines across (will apply bottom margin later, once I get rid of this 2px margin appearing between the lists)

Comment: I can but that's all, it's a segregated case and no dependency

Comment: I tried that before also, no effect, updated the code as well.

Comment: an observation. I took snapshots in photoshop, zoomed in, the li elements are gaining height because of the border, 2px height plus 1px border

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
border-bottom-width:1px solid red;
```

Comment: you can set size of width using this.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what you're asking; but it seems as though your complaint is with the border adding to the height of your list item. If this is the case, set `box-sizing: border-box` on the list items.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/Z6t6A/

Comment: to clarify, everything works if I remove border property, but if add border property, all of my list item elements gain a height of 2px (border width is additional). I draw 2 black pixels to indicate that in the screenshot

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper I understand that; borders (by default) add to the height of your element. You can prevent this by setting `box-sizing: border-box` on the list items. See my "fiddle" for a demo.

Comment: yes I've seen that, actually let me rephrase, I want to get rid of this 2px height, it came from no where, and it's a side effect if I add borders to list items.

Comment: I've added screenshot from chrome, my desired output, see all of the borders are like attached to each other, but IE is having a gap, it's not margin or padding, IE is giving height of 2px to each list item

Comment: I have no idea what your screenshots are supposed to communicate. I'm sorry. Can you tell us again what you want to do?

Comment: yes sure, let me try again with context. Kindly lookup barchart image at http://jcharts.sourceforge.net/samples/images/samples/clusteredBar/clusteredBarChart.png (see the horizontal lines behind, I'm trying to generate that through list items using border). For accuracy I wanted to be assure, there are no margins, paddings and no height of li elements before I put spacing between them but as you can see from the first image, IE is culprit and giving height of 2px to li's for no reason

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper Why are you trying to build barcharts with lists? Why not use a canvas instead?

Comment: Yes good question, I've to be backward compatible up to ie6, and have to do it in plain, JavaScript, css. Seems like this is kinda ie bug that was not discovered.